# Is p|(q|r) is it equivalent to (q and r)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Using De Morgan's laws can I turn $p|(q|r)$ into: $(q \ and \ r)$ 
or does the and become an or, such as $(q \ or \ r)$ ?

Comment: $p|(q|r)≡¬(p∧(q∧r))≡¬p∨¬(q∧r)≡¬p∨¬q∨¬r$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $|$ means NAND. First of all you can easily see that your assertion is false, since for $p=q=r=0$ the LHS is 1 where the RHS is 0. (Also you should be suspicious of losing the dependence in $p$.)

Using a Karnaugh map, one can easily see that $p|(q|r)$ simplifies to $\overline{p}+q\wedge r$.